# R- creating a counter-party frequency matrix

Tags: r, frequency

I have data from a barter economy. I am trying to create a matrix that counts how frequently items act as counterparties with other items.

As an example:

```
  myDat <- data.frame(
             TradeID = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8)),
             Origin = as.factor(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)),
             ItemID = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,1,6,7,1,1,8,7,5,1,1,2,3,4))
            )


     TradeID Origin ItemID
  1        1      1      1
  2        1      0      2
  3        1      0      3
  4        2      1      4
  5        2      1      5
  6        2      0      1
  7        3      1      1
  8        3      0      6
  9        4      1      7
  10       4      0      1
  11       5      1      1
  12       5      0      8
  13       6      1      7
  14       6      0      5
  15       7      1      1
  16       7      0      1
  17       8      1      2
  18       8      0      3
  19       8      0      4
  20       9      1      1
  21       9      0      8
```

*Where TradeID indicates a specific transaction. ItemID indicates an item, and Origin indicates which direction the item went.*

For example, given my data the matrix I'd create would look something like this: 
      [image]

- For example, the value 2 at [1,8] indicates that item 1 & 8 were counterparties in two trades. (Note that it's a symmetric matrix, and so [8,1] also has the value 2).
- While the value of 1 at [1,2] indicates that item 1 and 2 were counterparties in only one trade (all the other 1s throughout the matrix indicate the same)
- As an odd example, note at [1,1], the value of 1 indicates that item 1 was a counterparty to itself once (trade number 7)
- A little extra insight into my motivation, note in my simple example that item 1 tends to act as counterparty with many different items. In a barter economy (one without explicit money) we might expect a commodity currency to be a counterparty relatively more frequently than non-commodity-currencies. A matrix like this would be the first step at one way of discovering which item was a commodity currency.

---

I've been struggling with this for a while. But I think I'm nearly done with an overly complicated solution, which I'll post shortly.

I'm curious if y'all might offer a bit of help also.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the matrix is supposed to show? For example, what does the 2 indicate at [1,8]? What does the 1 indicate at [5,7]? Etc.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. I've added a bit of extra explanation under the example matrix. I'm sorry for my lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I think I've got this figured out. The short answer is:

```
Reduce("+",by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) pmin(table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) + table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]),1)))
```

Which gives the following matrix, matching the desired result:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
3 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
8 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here's the long answer. You can get a list of matrices for each `TradeID` using the `by` and `outer` (`%o%`) and `table` functions. But this double-counts Trade 7, where item 1 is traded for item 1, so I use the `pmax` function to fix this. Then I sum across the list by using the `Reduce` function.

And here's the steps to get there. Note the addition of TradeID # 9, which was left out of the question's code.

```
# Data
myDat <- data.frame(
  TradeID = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,9)),
  Origin = as.factor(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)),
  ItemID = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,1,6,7,1,1,8,7,5,1,1,2,3,4,1,8))
)

# Sum in 1 direction
by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]))

# Sum in both directions
by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) + table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]))

# Remove double-count in trade 7
by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) pmin(table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) + table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]),1))

# Sum across lists
Reduce("+",by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) pmin(table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) + table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]),1)))
```

One way to speed this up would be to sum in only 1 direction (taking advantage of symmetry) and then clean up the results.

```
result = Reduce("+",by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1])))
result2 = result + t(result)
diag(result2) = diag(result)
result2
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
  2 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
  3 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  4 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  7 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  8 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This appears to run nearly twice as fast.

```
> microbenchmark(Reduce("+",by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) pmin(table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) + table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]),1))))
Unit: milliseconds
      min       lq   median       uq     max neval
 7.489092 7.733382 7.955861 8.536359 9.83216   100

> microbenchmark(Reduce("+",by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1]))))
Unit: milliseconds

      min      lq   median       uq      max neval
 4.023964 4.18819 4.277767 4.452824 5.801171   100
```

Comment: Thank you for the working solution. I am curious, @Nick, if I might be so bold as to ask your suggestion for a method that gets the code to run a bit faster and/or with lower memory requirement? I've tried to run it over my sample (which averages 50,000 - 150,000 trades a day, with about 3500 items), but the server I have access to has to tends to run out of memory.

Comment: You could cut almost in half by summing in only 1 direction, taking advantage of the symmetry. So something like `Reduce("+",by(myDat, myDat$TradeID, function(x) table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==0]) %o% table(x$ItemID[x$Origin==1])))` and then cleaning up the result afterwards. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: You could also try running the code in batches and then summing the results at the end, since it's summing across `TradeID` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the number of observations per TradeID and ItemID

```
myDat <- data.frame(
  TradeID = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8)),
  Origin = as.factor(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)),
  ItemID = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,1,6,7,1,1,8,7,5,1,1,2,3,4))
)
result = tapply(myDat$Origin, list(myDat$ItemID,myDat$TradeID), length)
result[is.na(result)] = 0
result["1","7"]
```

result will then be:

```
> result
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0
2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
5 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
6 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
8 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

This will give you the proportion of `1` `Origin` per TradeID and ItemID

```
result = tapply(myDat$Origin, list(myDat$ItemID,myDat$TradeID), function(x) { sum(as.numeric(as.character(x)))/length(x) })
```

You can set the `NA` values in the last matrix to 0 using `result[is.na(result)] = 0` but that would confuse no observations with nothing but `0` Origin trades.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the number of observations per consecutive `ItemID`s:

```
idxList <-  with(myDat, tapply(ItemID, TradeID, FUN = function(items) 
  lapply(seq(length(items) - 1), 
         function(i) sort(c(items[i], items[i + 1])))))

# indices of observations  
idx <- do.call(rbind, unlist(idxList, recursive = FALSE))

# create a matrix
ids <- unique(myDat$ItemID)
mat <- matrix(0, length(ids), length(ids))

# place values in matrix
for (i in seq(nrow(idx))) {
  mat[idx[i, , drop = FALSE]] <- mat[idx[i, , drop = FALSE]] + 1      
}

# create symmatric marix 
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[lower.tri(mat)]


     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    2    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    2    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
[6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[7,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
[8,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```